# How do I test pending transactions in Google Play Billing Library 2

Tags: in-app-purchase, in-app

I am trying to use Google Play Billing 2 on my game. In documentation, it says:

> **Test pending transactions with license testers**
>
> *Pending transactions can be tested using license testers. In addition
>   to two test credit cards, license testers have access to two test
>   instruments for delayed forms of payment which automatically complete
>   or cancel after a couple of minutes.*

My question is, how exactly to test it? Can I test it without credit card? Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you figure this out yet ?